# MDX YTD over range (:)

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Does YTD can handle date range ?

I'm trying to compare a period of X days of the current year with the same period of the prior year.

My MDX query looks like this :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Prior YTD Amount] AS SUM
(
   YTD
   (
      ParallelPeriod
      (
         [Date].[Year],
         1,
         [Date].CurrentMember
      )
   )
   ,
   [Measures].[Amount]
)
set [ColSet] as
{
   [Measures].[Amount],
   [Measures].[Prior YTD Amount]
}
set [RowSet] as
{
   [Motif].[Categorie].Members
}
SELECT
NON EMPTY [ColSet] ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [RowSet] ON ROWS
FROM [Things]
WHERE
{
   [Date].[2015].[2].[1]:[Date].[2015].[2].[9]
}
```

I'm working with Mondrian 3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short this code will not work. Reason being that the following line of code is looking for a single member of the hierarchy you've applied the `Currentmember` to:

`[Date].CurrentMember`

You have more than one member in the set `[Date].[2015].[2].[1]:[Date].[2015].[2].[9]`

---

Here is a small proof of the above:

This script:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Key 
SELECT 
  {[Product].[Category].[All Products]} ON 0
 ,{[Measures].[x]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080322]
  };
```

Returns this:

[image]

Whereas this script:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[x] AS 
    [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {[Product].[Category].[All Products]} ON 0
 ,{[Measures].[x]} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  {
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080322]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080323]
  };
```

Returns this:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

---

In `AdvWrks` I just wrote the following which might help, if you can move your target range of dates from the `WHERE` clause to a named set.

How it works:

1.Finds the first date in your named set via `.Item(0).Item(0)`
2.Finds the last date in your named set via `.Item([myStartDates].Count - 1).Item(0)`
3.The uses the two dates found to create a range that is parallel

```
WITH 
  SET [myStartDates] AS 
    {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080322]
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080323]
    } 
  SET [parallelToFirst] AS 
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
     ,1
     ,[myStartDates].Item(0).Item(0)
    ) 
  SET [parallelToLast] AS 
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
     ,1
     ,[myStartDates].Item(
      [myStartDates].Count - 1).Item(0)
    ) 
  SET [Rebuild] AS 
    [parallelToFirst].Item(0) : [parallelToLast].Item(0) 
SELECT 
  {} ON COLUMNS
 ,[Rebuild] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Easy enough to then Sum that range and pop it in the date dimension:

```
WITH 
  SET [myStartDates] AS 
    {
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080322]
      : 
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080323]
    } 
  SET [parallelToFirst] AS 
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
     ,1
     ,[myStartDates].Item(0).Item(0)
    ) 
  SET [parallelToLast] AS 
    ParallelPeriod
    (
      [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
     ,1
     ,[myStartDates].Item(
      [myStartDates].Count - 1).Item(0)
    ) 
  SET [ParallelRange] AS 
    [parallelToFirst].Item(0) : [parallelToLast].Item(0) 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[parallelSum] AS 
    Sum([ParallelRange]) 
SELECT 
  {
    [myStartDates]
   ,[ParallelRange]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[parallelSum]
  } ON 0
 ,{
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Order Quantity]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Here is the result (just to prove it is doing what we want):

[image]

Comment: Hey, nice attempt. Have added one more possible approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i have to make it match my use : my process have to generate this kind of queries...

Comment: @jBravo I'm unsure how Mondrian works - is there some way of introducing parameters? In `SSRS` it is possible. In `Pyramid` (which I get to play with) it is very easy: so I can easily parameterize the first set `[myStartDates]`

Comment: Ok, i will have a look to Pyramid. Thanks again!

Comment: Do you have a solution for a semi-additive measure like average?

Comment: @jBravo so in the above instead of parallelSum you would like parallelAvg ?  Just change this  `Sum([ParallelRange])`  to this  `Avg([ParallelRange])`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an alternative approach, to using `ParallelPeriods` function. 
I am assuming you have all the dates from prev year in the cube, i.e. there are no missing dates in between or "gaps". If so, you can use the `LAG` function to hop over to the date 365 days(1 year) back. Also, have the dates from current year initially in a set. That way you can parametrize them easily.

Your final MDX should look somewhat similar to:

```
with set Dates as
{
  [Date].[2015].[2].[1]
  :
  [Date].[2015].[2].[9]
}//<<This can be also written as 
 //StrToSet("{[Date]."+ @DateStart + ":" +  "[Date]."+ @DateEnd + "}")
//@Date1 and @Date2 being the parameters you can pass from front end

set datesPrevYear as
{
  head(Dates, 1).item(0).LAG(365).item(0) \\<<Gets the starting date's 1 year previous date
  : 
  tail(Dates, 1).item(0).LAG(365).item(0) \\<<Gets the ending date's 1 year previous date
} 

member [Measures].[Prior YTD Amount] as
sum(datesPrevYear, [Measures].[Amount])

set [ColSet] as
{
  [Measures].[Amount],
  [Measures].[Prior YTD Amount]
}
set [RowSet] as
{
  [Motif].[Categorie].Members
}

select
non empty [ColSet] on columns,
non empty [RowSet] on rows
from [Things]
```

Comment: please add logic for leap year

Comment: Oh man! That will be a drag. Maybe later I will add the rest of the logic.

Comment: he matey: don't worry I was only teasing you really. I just noticed the hardcoded `365`.